# How to access internet and run apt-get through a middle server?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a machine running ubuntu 16.04. The machine can only access 1 remote server (also running ubuntu). The remote server has full access to internet though.

```
root@localmachine:~# ifconfig usb0
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:1e:10:1f:00:00  
          inet addr:10.1.0.94  Bcast:10.1.0.95  Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4366027 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1813925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:669835698 (669.8 MB)  TX bytes:265999026 (265.9 MB)

root@localmachine:~# ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=58.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=59.2 ms
```

I need to install some package on this local machine via apt-get.

Is there a way to access internet throught the public server at 10.0.0.1 ?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: do you have `ssh` access to that server?

Comment: yes. i can run ssh root@10.0.0.1 and access the public server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be that you set up a proxy server on the middle server/gateway and set up your apt to use this proxy:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

And add this line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I failed with the SOCKS setup from the RoVo. But it seems setting up a squid proxy server at 10.0.0.1 does indeed work

Answer (score 16):

Open a terminal and start `ssh` dynamic port forwarding:

```
ssh -D 1080 root@10.0.0.1
```

This will start a socks proxy on your computer on port 1080.

Add this line to your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file:

```
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks5h://localhost:1080";
```

Then you can run your `apt update` / `apt install` commands. When you're done, you can close the `ssh` connection and revert the changes in `apt.conf`.

You can also tell your Browser or other applications to [use that Socks proxy](https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/) and access the Internet.

Comment: I run the command and get this error: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/a/autossh/autossh_1.4e-2_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to 1080:80 (0.0.4.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument)

Comment: the dynamic port forwarding seems to be correct: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21096/ssh

Comment: Do i need to setup the remote server as a proxy server ?

Comment: sorry, the line in `apt.conf` was wrong, I edited that. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you. Now i get a  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' error. Look like a DNS problem. Should I install a local DNS server or do you have any suggesstion ?

Comment: The DNS request is not sent via Socks Proxy, in apt.conf, change `socks5://` to `socks5h://`, that should work, fingers crossed. Sorry, it's difficult to test for me, because I have connection ...

Comment: With this config line, I got an error "Temporary failure resolving". But changing "Acquire::socks::proxy" to "Acquire::http::Proxy" resolved the issue!